# Nazir benefiting from grapes/wine

Tags: halacha, grapes-wine, nozir, hanaah-benefit, maseches-nazir

If somebody vows to be a Nazir, are they still allowed to benefit from wine and grapes? Like would they be able to sell wine and grapes to non Nazir people? Or is it like milk and meat or chametz on Passover where you are forbidden from benefiting, not just eating it. Sources appreciated please

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.37a.7?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en

Comment: I haven't properly learnt the sugya so don't want to post it until I have further checked it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Nazir is allowed to benefit from wine, as the gemara (pesachim 21b-23a) says:

> ופליגי דרבי אבהו דאמר רבי אבהו כל מקום שנאמר לא יאכל לא תאכל לא תאכלו אחד איסור אכילה ואחד איסור הנאה עד שיפרט לך הכתוב כדרך שפרט לך בנבילה... (23.) והרי נזיר דרחמנא אמר "מחרצנים ועד זג לא יאכלו ותנן "מערבין לנזיר ביין" אמר מר זוטרא שאני התם דאמר קרא "נזרו" שלו יהא
>
> And this argued with Rabbi Abahu, as Rabbi Abahu says, anywhere that "it shall not be eaten", "you shall not eat" or "you (plu.) should not eat" is written, it means both a prohibition of eating and a prohibition of benefitting, until the passuk says outright, like by *neveila*... (23b) [the gemara questions Rabbi Abahu] but by a Nazir it says "they shall eat nothing from the seeds to the grape skin", yet we learned in a mishna "we make an eiruv (techumin) for a Nazir with wine"! **Mar Zutra answers: there it is different, as the Passuk says "his Nazir-hood" - it shall be his. (Meaning, even though he isn't allowed to eat or drink the grape products, he is allowed to benefit from them, as they are still considered his, as the Passuk calls it *his* Nazir-hood)**

So we see that a Nazir may derive benefit from grape products. However, it's slightly more complicated than that, as the Ramba'm (Nazir 5:10) writes:

> מדברי סופרים שאסור לנזיר לעמוד במושב שותי יין ויתרחק ממנו הרבה שהרי מכשול לפניו. אמרו חכמים סביב לכרם לא יקרב
>
> Mid'rabannan, it is prohibited for a Nazir to stand in a place of wine-drinkers, and he should distance himself from it a lot, as it is a stumbling block for him. Chachamim said that he should not walk in the vicinity of a vineyard

(This is based on a gemara in Avoda Zara 59)

So we see that a Nazir should not deal with wine or grapes in any form, even when they're not his own, as he may come to eat/ drink them. In short, a Nazir may get benefit from grape products, so long as he is not in the direct surroundings of the grapes. For example, he can't sell grapes, but he can have someone else sell grapes for him.